# CalendarContract not setting calendar name properly

Tags: android, calendar

I'm creating a calendar programatically, and everything is setted well but the calendar's name. This is the method I'm using.

```
private Uri createCalendar(String email){
        Uri target = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI.toString());
        target = target.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, email)
                .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google").build();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, email);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Util.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, email);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAN_PARTIALLY_UPDATE, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC1, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + email + "/private/full");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC2, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full/" + email);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC3, "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full/" + email);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC4, 1);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC5, 0);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC8, System.currentTimeMillis());

        Uri newCalendar = context.getContentResolver().insert(target, values);

        return newCalendar;
    }
```

As said, everything is working fine, the color, the owner account, etc. but when the calendar is created, the name of it is always "Events". I tried to put the name manually (not using `getStrings()`) but didn't work either.

Any ideas of what can be happening?